# Why can't I instantiate the POSIX package in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop, posix

I am not up to something here, I am just experimenting.

So I tried

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX;
```

can I do something like:

```
my $point = bless {}, 'POSIX';
print $point->strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y", @time);
```

Tried that one it gives error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That won't work, because the functions in the `POSIX` package are not designed to be called as object methods.

When you call a method using the `->` operator, Perl finds the method in the invocant's inheritance hierarchy and then executes it, passing the invocant in as the first parameter. So

```
$point->strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y", @time);
```

is equivalent to:

```
POSIX::strftime( $point, "%A, %B %d, %Y", @time );
```

The `strftime` function is not expecting that extra parameter on the beginning, so it dies with a standard XS usage error.